# How can I apply np.apply_along_axis to combination of two arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Arrays of labels of objects and distances to that objects are given. I want to apply knn to find the label of prediction. I want to use `np.bincount` for that. However, I don't understand how to use this.
See some example

```
labels = [[1,1,2,0,0,3,3,3,5,1,3],
          [1,1,2,0,0,3,3,3,5,1,3]]

weights= [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]]
```

Imagine 10 nearest neighbors for 2 objects are given and their labels and distances are given above. So I want the output as `[5,5]`, because only neighbours with that label have nonzero weight. I am doing the next thing:

```
eps = 1e-5
lab_weight = np.array(list(zip(labels, weights)))
predict = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x[0], weights=x[1]).argmax(), 2, lab_weight)
```

I expect that `x` will correspond to `[[1,1,2,0,0,3,3,3,5,1,3],  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]]`, but it won't. Other axis parameters are not working too. How can I achieve the goal? I want to use `numpy` functions and avoid python loops.

Comment: You don't. It's a function for iterating through **one** array. `apply` doesn't avoid those loops. It just hides then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next solution gives me desired result:

```
labels = [[1,1,2,0,0,3,3,3,5,1,3],
          [1,1,2,0,0,3,3,3,5,1,3]]

weights= [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]]
length = len(labels[0])
lab_weight = np.hstack((labels, weights))
predict = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x[:length], weights=x[length:]).argmax(), 1, lab_weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you attempt to use your
function to **2-D** slices of your array, whereas *apply_along_axis*
applies the given function to **1-D** slices.

So your code generates an exception: *ValueError: object of too small
depth for desired array*.

To apply your function to 2-D slices, use a list comprehension based on
*np.rollaxis* and then create a *Numpy* array from it:

```
result = np.array([ np.bincount(x[0], weights=x[1]).argmax()
    for x in np.rollaxis(lab_weight, 2) ])
```

The result, for your array, is:

```
array([1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

To trace, for each interation, the source array, intermediate results
and the final result, run:

```
i = 0
for x in np.rollaxis(lab_weight, 2):
    print(f'  i: {i}\n{x}'); i += 1
    bc = np.bincount(x[0], weights=x[1])
    bcm = bc.argmax()
    print(bc, bcm)
```